# What is difference between “+” and “~” selector in CSS?

Tags: css

I have used these selector. However, not able to get the difference them.

It seems like they both work same. Their must be some difference which I am not able to get.

Comment: You *did* try to read some documentation on the topic...?! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference#Selectors

Comment: and another source, JUST GOOGLE IT : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: I don't have much more to add to the other comments.. but a simple Google would have given you the answer, you should awlays try Google first.

Comment: on SO at CSS tag  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css (under the tag where sits your question)  click on INFO (menu) takes you here > http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info and second link in text is about selector and it takes you here >   https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ and finally read donwn here about it https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`+` will only select the first element that is immediately preceded by the former selector.

`~` selector all the sibling preceded by the former selector.

```css
.plusSelector + div {
  background: red
}
.tiltSelector ~ div {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<h3>+ Selector</h3>
<div class="example1">
  <div class="plusSelector">test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>

<h3>~ Selector</h3>
<div class="example1">
  <div class="tiltSelector">test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `+` symbol is inmediatelly sibling, but `~` symbol allows you to target siblings in random position (always after the reference element)

### Example with `+`:

```css
input + label {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<label>My label</label>

<input type="text">
<p>A paragraph</p>
<label>My label</label>
```

### Example with `~`:

```css
input ~ label {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<label>My label</label>

<input type="text">
<p>A paragraph</p>
<label>My label</label>
```

Comment: with such high reputation I wouldn't expect you to answer it, it deserves to be closed

Comment: @moped can you mark as duplicated with a canonical question exactly as this? If yes, my apologies, I will remove my answer. If not, there's no reason to close.

Comment: And there are another answer with someone who has more reputation than me, and without coding examples :(

Comment: if you were talking about me, there is some code :)

Comment: I mean, no offense to you, but it's just so basic question, that I'd give a comment (that I did) and then close it ..

Comment: @dippas yeah, sorry :).

Comment: @moped simple questions, and easy questions, don't need to be invalid questions. I know this is solvable googling 2 minutes, but stackoverflow is full of this questions, and some of them have many upvotes. Weird? OK. But is not a practice against the stackoverflow rules. I guess. If I'm mistaken please, let me know.

Comment: However, I don't see any closing votes, because there are no specific category to close this. "Google it" is not a reason.